# Compare two big arrays value for value in Node.js

Tags: arrays, node.js, performance, compare

I have two arrays, one containing 200.000 product objects coming from a CSV file and one containing 200.000 product objects coming from a database.

Both arrays contains objects with the same fields, with one exception: the database objects have a unique ID as well.

I need to compare all 200.000 CSV objects with the 200.000 database objects. If the CSV object already exists in the database objects array I put it in an "update" array together with the ID from the match, and if it doesn't, then I put it in a "new" array.

When done, I update all the "update" objects in the database, and insert all the "new" ones. This goes fast (few seconds).

The compare step however takes hours. I need to compare three values: the channel (string), date (date) and time (string). If all three are the same, it's a match. If one of those isn't, then it's not a match.

This is the code I have:

```
  const newProducts = []; 
  const updateProducts = [];
  csvProducts.forEach((csvProduct) => {

    // check if there is a match
    const match = dbProducts.find((dbProduct) => {
      return dbProduct.channel === csvProduct.channel && moment(dbProduct.date).isSame(moment(csvProduct.date), 'day') && dbProduct.start_time === csvProduct.start_time;
    });

    if (match) {
      // we found a match, add it to updateProducts array
      updateProducts.push({
        id: match.id,
        ...csvProduct
      });

      // remove the match from the dbProducts array to speed things up
      _.pull(dbProducts, match);
    } else {
      // no match, it's a new product
      newProducts.push(csvProduct);
    }
  });
```

I am using `lodash` and `moment.js` libraries.

The bottleneck is in the check if there is a match, any ideas on how to speed this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for the [`Map` collection class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).  Arrays are a hassle because they must be searched linearly. Maps (and [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)) can be searched fast. You want to do your matching in RAM rather than hitting your db for every single object in your incoming file.

So, first read every record in your database and construct a Map where the keys are objects like this  `{start_time, date, channel}` and the values are `id`. (I put the time first because I guess it's the attribute with the most different values. It's an attempt to make lookup faster.)

Something like this pseudocode.

```
 const productsInDb = new Map()
 for (const entry in database) {
     const key = {  // make your keys EXACTLY the same when you load your Map ..
         start_time: entry.start_time,
         date: moment(entry.date), 
         entry.channel}
     productsInDb.add(key, entry.id)
 }
```

This will take a whole mess of RAM, but so what? It's what RAM is for.

Then do your matching more or less the way you did it in your example, but using your Map.

```
const newProducts = []; 
const updateProducts = [];
csvProducts.forEach((csvProduct) => {

  // check if there is a match
  const key = {     // ...and when you look up entries in the Map.
         start_time: entry.start_time,
         date: moment(entry.date), 
         entry.channel}
  const id = productsInDb.get(key)
  if (id) {
      // we found a match, add it to updateProducts array
      updateProducts.push({
         id: match.id,
        ...csvProduct
      });
      // don't bother to update your Map here 
      // unless you need to do something about dups in your csv file
  } else {
    // no match, it's a new product
    newProducts.push(csvProduct)
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks, that did the trick! it's only a matter of seconds now :)

Comment: Cool. Hours to seconds.  O(n**2) to O(n log n) always makes a difference.